# React - how to target value from a form with onClick

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios

New to react and currently working on a project with a backend.
Everything functions correctly apart from targeting the value of user selection.

basically whenever a user enters a number the `setId` is saved properly to the const with no problems while using the `onChange` method.

this method would render my page every change on text.

I am trying to save the Id only when the user clicks the button. however,
`event.target.value` does not work with `onClick`.

I tried using `event.currentTarget.value` and this does not seem to work.

**Code:**

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Company ID</label>
                <input value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} type="number" />
                {/* <button value={id} type="button" onClick={(e) => setId(e.currentTarget.value)}>Search</button> */}
            </form>
```

**Handle Submit:**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(id)
    
}
```

is there a way of doing this with onclick? since I wouldn't like my component to render on every typo and only once a user has clicked the `button`.

**Componenet:**

```
interface GetOneCompanyProps {
    company: CompanyModel;
}

interface RouteParam {
    id: any;
}

interface CompanyById extends RouteComponentProps<RouteParam> {

}

function GetOneCompany(): JSX.Element {

    const [id, setId] = useState('4');
    const [company, setCompany] = useState<any>('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(id)
        
    }

    async function send() {


        try {
            const response = await axios.get<CompanyModel>(globals.adminUrls.getOneCompany + id)

            store.dispatch(oneCompanyAction(response.data));
            console.log(response);
            const company = response.data;
            setCompany(company)

        } catch (err) {
            notify.error(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        send();

    }, [id]);


    return (
        <div className="getOneCompany">
            <h1>hi  </h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Company ID</label>
                <input value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)} type="number" />
                {/* <button value={id} type="button" onClick={(e) => setId(e.currentTarget.value)}>Search</button> */}
            </form>
            
            <div className="top">
            </div>
            <br/>
            Company: {id}
            <br/>
            Client Type: {company.clientType}
            <br/>
            Company Name: {company.name}
            <br/>
            Email Adress: {company.email}
            <br/>
        </div>

    );
}

export default GetOneCompany;
```

Hope I am clear on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I would HIGHLY recommend using a library like https://formik.org/, it makes dealing with forms in React so much easier :)

Comment: I am curious though, why do you need to get the `id` from the form on submit when you're already setting it in your components state?  You could just POST a json payload using that ID

Comment: @Halfpint I want that only when a user submits a button it will render and not when its passing auto while typing.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your usecase, could you please make a JSFiddle or CodePen? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your input from being a *controlled* input to an *uncontrolled* input, and make use of the `useRef` hook. Basically, remove most of your attributes from the input element, and grab the current value of the input form on click of the button. From there, you can do whatever you want with the input value.

```
const inputRef = useRef()

...other code

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <label>Company ID</label>
  <input type="number" ref={inputRef} />
  <button value={id} type="button" onClick={() => console.log(inputRef.current.value)}>Search</button>
</form>

...other code
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say that here onChange is mandatory as we also are interested in the value which we set by setId. onClick can't be used as we can't set the value in the input.
Hope I'm clear.
Thankyou!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).